# How to write to a matrix within a while loop in a monte carlo simulation in python 3

Tags: python, matrix, while-loop, simulation, montecarlo

Okay so I am trying to complete the infection simulation code for a monte carlo simulation in python.
We were given the thread shell and just need to complete this. I will also have to add a vaccine  function but it should be pretty similar to the infect function so Im trying to make sure that it works first. I know that I need to read from my original matrix but write to a new matrix for each day/iteration, but I can't figure out how to write to the new matrix. I tried using np.append but it forced me to redefine my original matrix A, or it said that list indices must be integers, not floats. I've tried working through examples on here and other places, but they all seem to be using lists or they don't involve calling a function within the while loop.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import random
import math
import numpy as np



def infect(Pop,i,j,n,m,tau):
    t = 0
    if (i > 1) and (i < n) and (j > 1) and (j < m):
        if (Pop[i-1,j]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
        if (Pop[i,j+1]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
        if (Pop[i+1,j]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
        if (Pop[i,j-1]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
    if (i == 1) and (j == 1):
        if (Pop[i,j+1]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
        if (Pop[i+1,j]):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
    if (i == 1) and (j != m) and (j > 1):
        if (Pop[i,j]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
        if (Pop[i+1,j]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
        if (Pop[i,j-1]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
    if (i == 1) and (j == m):
        if (Pop[i+1,j]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
        if (Pop[i,j-1]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
    if (i == n) and (j == 1):
        if (Pop[i-1,j]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
        if (Pop[i,j+1]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
    if (i < n) and (i > 1) and (j == 1):
        if (Pop[i-1,j]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
        if (Pop[i,j+1]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
        if (Pop[i+1,j]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
    if (i < n) and (i > 1) and (j == m):
        if (Pop[i-1,j]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
        if (Pop[i+1,j]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
        if (Pop[i,j-1]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
    if (i == n) and (j > 1) and (j < m):
        if (Pop[i-1,j]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
        if (Pop[i,j+1]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
        if (Pop[i,j-1]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
    if (i == n) and (j == m):
        if (Pop[i,j-1]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)
        if (Pop[i-1,j]>0):
            t = (np.random.rand() < tau)       

    p = 0
    if (t==True):
        p = 1
    return p


i = 1
j = 1
n = 10
m = 10
k = int(input("Number of Days to Recover from Illness?"))
d = 0.0
tau = 0.5
mu = 0.2
A = np.zeros((n,m))
if d == 0:
    n1 = random.sample(range(n),1)
    m1 = random.sample(range(m),1)
    A[n1,m1] = 1
    print(A)

while d < 100:
    while True:

        if (A[i,j]==0):
            x = infect(A,i,j,n,m,tau)
        print(x)
                #A_new.append(x)
```

Comment: I notice that you changed your original question significantly, such that someone who reads it may now have a hard time understanding how the answers (esp. the accepted one) relate. I recommend strongly against doing that ever. It is good to clarify, but the above question now has two questions (one about improper indexing, the other about how to terminate a loop on certain conddition), unrelated to A/B copy. Given that you got an answer you found useful for your original, you should undo your last edit to leave the original question, and instead create two new questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create an extra matrix and every time through the loop you swap the two references. For example,

```
A1 = np.zeros((m, n))
A2 = np.zeros((m, n))
Anow = A1 # reference, not copy
Aafter = A2
while d < 100:
    x = infectAll(Anow, Aafter, n,m,tau)
    Anow, Aafter = Aafter, Anow
```

and infectAll() sweeps over the whole matrix so it would be something like

```
def infectAll(Ain, Aout, n, m, tau):
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
             if Anow[i,j] == 0:
                  Aafter[i,j] = infect(Anow, i, j, n, m, tau)
```

I like Andrei's more compact code but there is no need to create a new copy of A every time, so the best would be to combine the above technique with Andrei's approach.

Comment: how can i get the while loop to terminate when all matrix values are <0?

Comment: @SaraWiles13 This is an additional question. A comment is not a good place for this, as people can't tell what you have tried, and can't format code etc. I recommend you create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need dynamic of your infection matrix and tau is probability of neighbor infection. You can use 3-dimensional array for this and optimize your code like this:

```
from copy import copy
import numpy as np
def infect(A, tau):
    B = copy(A)
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            is_infected = False
            for neighbor in [A[i-1,j], A[i+1,j], A[i,j-1], A[i,j+1]]:
                if neighbor: 
                    B[i,j] = int(A[i,j] or (np.random.rand() < tau))
    return B

D = np.zeros((T + 1, m, n))
A = np.zeros((m, n))
A[i,j] = 1
for t in range(T):
    D[t,:,:] = A
    A = infect(A, tau)
D[T,:,:] = A
```

Comment: Okay, I thought that using a for loop would free up alot of unnecessary code but I just wasn't sure how to use the copy(),Thank you!

Comment: Also, how did you define T here?

Comment: would it be in place of iterations k

Comment: nvm figured it out :)

Comment: Sure, my T is the same that your k